# Weird google bot crawl problem

Tags: buddypress, text, browser-compatibility

I have moved my website to a VPS server. It is a Wordpress + Buddypress installation, latest versions.

I don't understand why I can't see anything when I visit my site with Lynx - a text browser. I can see other sites using wordpress on the same server, but this one doesn't work.
Also blogs created on the platform also work fine in Lynx, but the pages of the website don't.

Guess that's why my website also was removed from google search results.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense without URL of your site and taking a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, there was a plugin activated for mobile browsers support - Smooci (WordPress on Mobiles).

The plugin was enabled, and no theme chosen for it. So instead showing the default theme, the plugin, broke out my website - showing nothing/blank page on mobiles.

Unfortunately the same plugin could not make the difference between a mobile browser and a text-only browser like Google Bot or Lynx.

Deactivated the plugin and problem solved.

Also posted a notice on wordpress forums:  http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-smooci-wordpress-on-mobiles-this-plugin-may-cause-your-website-to-be-removed-from-google-search-results?replies=1

Comment: select your answer as correct answer if the approach works for you.